# Fastest way to install wire trunking?

Tags: wiring

My hand is not that strong to hammer those concrete nails into trunking+wall.

May I know what tool should I use for this purpose?

Comment: Have you looked into adhesive based systems, or using a small hammer drill with concrete screws?

Comment: Yes I do consider, but will they last for decades?

Considering abrasive glue + silicon.

Comment: A threaded concrete anchor like tapcons would last decades. A good silicone would be sturdy, but also re-positionable without damaging the wall

Comment: @BrownRedHawk implementation issue, I will have to drill the hole before driving in the anchor. 

When installing the trunking, it will be hard to estimate the position of the hole.

Well I can drill the hole together with the trucking too =x

Comment: This is common. Typically you would predrill the trunking, mark and drill holes in the concrete wall, then use an impact driver or power drill to secure the fastener. They go in to concrete  just like a screw into wood.

Comment: hmmm so drill or abrasive glue + silicon?

Comment: The mechanical fasteners, when installed correctly, would be my personal choice.